# Need a glob pattern to match all *.css files *except* for those with *.module.css

Tags: filenames, glob

I need a glob to match all `*.css` files *except* for CSS modules. For example, all of the following would match:

```
styles.css
global.css
global.one.css
```

...but the following would not:

```
styles.module.css
global.module.css
```

I've tried a handful of variations around `*!(.module).css` with no success. Am I misreading the function of the negation operator here?

Comment: Where do you read about a negation operator? What OS/shell are you running?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

`**/!(*.module).css`

You can try out glob patterns here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2A%2A%2F%21%28%2A.module%29.css&matches=false&tests=styles.css&tests=global.css&tests=global.one.css&tests=styles.module.css&tests=global.module.css